# Trouble deserializing XML into a List<T>

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, collections

Here's the XML file I'm trying to deserialize:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EntityType>
  <Name>SomeName</Name>
  <Components>
    <ComponentAssembly>Some assembly name</ComponentAssembly>
  </Components>
</EntityType>
```

And here is the Data contract I am using to deserialize it:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace GameUtilities.Entities.DataContracts
{
[DataContract(Name="EntityType",Namespace="")]
public class EntityTypeData
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired=true,Order = 0)]
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired=false,Order=1)]
    public List<ComponentEntry> Components { get; private set; }

    public EntityTypeData(string name, List<ComponentEntry> components = null)
    {
        Name = name;
        if(components == null)
        {
            Components = new List<ComponentEntry>();
        }
        else
        {
            Components = components;
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class ComponentEntry
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 0)]
    public string ComponentAssembly { get; private set; }

    public ComponentEntry(string componentAssembly)
    {
        ComponentAssembly = componentAssembly;
    }
}
}
```

Deserializing it works correctly, but the Components list is always empty, no matter how many entrys I put inside the  tags. I have tried marking the [DataMemeber] attribute for Components as "IsRequired=true", and deserialization still completes without error, but the List is not getting populated. Can you see any issues with my data contract that would make this fail?

EDIT: As a test, I ran an object using the Data Contract above through a serializer to see what XML got spat out. Here's what I saw:

```
<EntityType xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Name>TESTNAME</Name>
    <Components xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/GameUtilities.Entities.DataContracts">
        <a:ComponentEntry>
            <a:ComponentAssembly>ONE</a:ComponentAssembly>
        </a:ComponentEntry>
        <a:ComponentEntry>
            <a:ComponentAssembly>TWO</a:ComponentAssembly>
        </a:ComponentEntry>
        <a:ComponentEntry>
            <a:ComponentAssembly>THREE</a:ComponentAssembly>
        </a:ComponentEntry>
   </Components>
```

Here is the serialization code I used:

```
public static void SerializeObject<T>(string path, T obj)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path,FileMode.Create);
        XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(fs);
        DataContractSerializer ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));

        //Serialize the data to a file
        ser.WriteObject(writer, obj);
        writer.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
```

As you can see, there is a separate ComponentEntry being created for each ComponentAssembly that is listed. Is there a way to get rid of that and just get the ComponentAssembly?

Comment: Make your components setter public

Comment: post your serialization code please

Answer (score 0):

Easiest solution would be to define a collection data contract instead. I don't think there is a way to have the `ComponentEntry` as a separate type, when using `DataContractSerializer`.

```
[DataContract(Name="EntityType",Namespace="")]
public class EntityTypeData
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired=true,Order=0)]
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired=false,Order=1)]
    public ComponentList Components { get; private set; }

    public EntityTypeData(string name, IEnumerable<string> components = null)
    {
        Name = name;
        Components = new ComponentList();
        if(components != null)
        {
            Components.AddRange(components);
        }
    }
}

[CollectionDataContract(ItemName = "ComponentAssembly", Namespace="")]
public class ComponentList : List<string> {}
```

```
var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(EntityTypeData));
var entity = (EntityTypeData) ser.ReadObject(stream);
```